# Cannot add english locale for my country (CH)?

Tags: locale, date

I like having my system in English, but I hate this absurd 12h AM/PM system. So I wanted to configure the locales for Switezrland. I found [this](https://github.com/cbaconnier/ubuntu-locale-en_CH) `en_CH` repo and then :

```
$ sudo locale-gen
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.UTF-8... done
  en_BW.UTF-8... done
  en_CA.UTF-8... done
  en_CH.UTF-8... done
  en_DK.UTF-8... done
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
  en_HK.UTF-8... done
  en_IE.UTF-8... done
  en_IL.UTF-8... done
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
  en_NG.UTF-8... done
  en_NZ.UTF-8... done
  en_PH.UTF-8... done
  en_SG.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
  en_ZA.UTF-8... done
  en_ZM.UTF-8... done
  en_ZW.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.

$ locale -a | grep CH
en_CH
en_CH.utf8

$ locale-gen en_CH en_CH.UTF-8
Error: 'en_CH' is not a supported language or locale
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: What's the purpose of the command which triggers that error? It looks to me as if the `en_CH` locale has already been successfully generated. Maybe a reboot will help.

Comment: So why is this one still missing from the dpkg-reconfigure?

Comment: That's why I added "reboot" to my comment. :)

Comment: Another idea is to also add it to `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

after

```
sudo locale-gen
```

Comment: Not really because in the menu of dpkg-reconfigure I don’t have my locale shown